# Getting contact photo

Tags: android, contacts

I am having a problem getting a contact photo, the kind you see in the messaging app and new gmail notification. I have looked at a few example codes but nothing has worked for me, this is what I currently have

this should get the photo uri and turn it into a bitmap image to use or at least it seems

```
public static Bitmap getContactImage(long id,Context context){
    InputStream input = getPhoto(id,context);
    if(input == null){
        return null;
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
}

public static InputStream getPhoto(long contactId,Context context){
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    InputStream in = null;
    try{
        in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    return in;
}
```

and this is how I call

```
long contactID = 0;
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
                Cursor contact = context.getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {Data.CONTACT_ID},Email.ADDRESS  + "='" + from + "'",null,null);
                if(contact.moveToFirst() && contact != null){
                    contactID = contact.getLong(0);
                    image = getContactImage(contactID,context);
                }
```

I get the contact id fine (checked by searching the number for the person querying against) but then it does not find the contact photo. I know there is a photo because I am testing it against myself to make sure and I have a contact photo so I dont know what else I should do.

I always find navigating the contact provider very troublesome because there is so much to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, I did a query against the `RAW_CONTACT_ID` with the `MIMETYPE` and that gave me the photo I was looking for

```
Cursor p = context.getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {Photo.PHOTO},
                Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE+"'"
                ,null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
//Querying for all contacts(Apply selection parameter in query to get a specific contact)

Uri contacts = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

cur = null;
cur = Main.context.getContentResolver().query(contacts, null, null,
                    null, null);    

int contactIdIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID);
int contactId = cur.getInt(contactIdIndex);
```

// Photo

```
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

            Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

            Cursor cursor = cr
                    .query(
                            photoUri,
                            new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO },
                            null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);

                _conEntry.setPhoto(data);
//Data is the photo bytes for you

            }

            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

First, get an ID of the photo from the PHOTO_ID column of ContactsContract.Contacts table. Next, retrieve a byte array from PHOTO column (which is actually alias to DATA15) from ContactsContract.Data by ID you got in previous step. And, finally, decode that byte array using BitmapFactory to get a bitmap.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) are docs about this.

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work, I had to do `Cursor p = context.getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {Photo.PHOTO},
           Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE+"'"
           ,null,null);` and that have me the image